# MapView multitouch zoom vs. built-in zoom controls

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to solve the following problem with MapView in an Android aplication:

I draw a static overlay over the map, it's position is relative to screen top and I use its (x,y) point to detect and reverse geocode a location underneath it.

When I zoom using built-in zoom controls, the map center position is not changed and consequently the address marker points to is also the same regardless of zoom level.

However, when I zoom via multitouch, the map center is moved aside and in result my marker points to a new address after the zoom is finished.

Can someone please suggest a solution on how to stick to the same address when zooming the map via multitouch?

Thanks

Comment: if your static overlay isnt at at the center i dont see how its position on the map wont change when you zoom out either way. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @Urban if your fingers are off center when you are doing a two-finger zoom, it will shift the center towards the center of your fingers

Comment: @Urban, well yes - my marker is not at the center. But in case of built-in zoom controls it stays at the same address after zoom, and I'm looking for the same behavior when using multitouch

Comment: @Craigy i know that, but i was wondering how its working with the built-in zoom controls. If you zoom out (even with the built in controls) a static image thats not at the center will have its address changed...right?

Comment: @Urban yes, you're absolutely right, that's what I would expect